# Où que + subjonctif

Tags: grammaire

J'ai du mal à comprendre pourquoi dans cette phrase trouvée [ici](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/o%C3%B9-que-qui-que-quoi-quen.482595/):

> J'irai où qu'il le faut pour trouver mes aimés.

On a  mis au lieu d'*où que*:

> J'irais **où il** le faudra pour trouver mes aimés.

Mais par exemple, si je dis:

> Où qu'il le faille, j'irai pour trouver mes aimés.

Est-ce que ça c'est correct?

Et si je dis:

> J'irai où qu'il le faille pour trouver mes aimés.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pour moi la phrase

> Où qu'il le faille, j'irai pour trouver mes aimés.

n'est pas correcte. *le* ici ne représente rien. Pour parler du lieu où tu iras, il y a déjà **où**.
`j'irais -> ira où? -> où qu'il faille`.

Et donc pour tes deux phrases :

> Où qu'il faille (aller), j'irai pour trouver mes aimés.
>
> J'irai où qu'il faille pour trouver mes aimés.

---

Avec

> Qu'il *le* faille ou non, j'irais trouver mes aimés.

ou

> J'irais trouver mes aimés, qu'il *le* faille ou non.

On ne s'interroge plus d'*où* mais de la *nécessité*, et *le* ici sous-entend *le faire* qui remplace **aller trouver mes aimés**.

Comment: Donc, pourquoi la présence de "le" dans la correction de la première phrase?

Comment: @NicholasJ. La correction devrait être : `J'irais où il faudra pour trouver mes aimés.`